# Filled NSArray unintentionally loses its content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

An array is filled properly but when I try to access to content again, seems that is empty again!! trying to post as many code as necessary. Thanks for help.

I declare appData in .h file:

```
@interface userViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSArray *appData;

    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    IBOutlet UILabel *status;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *appData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *mainTable;


- (IBAction) refresca: (id)sender;

- (void)getData: (NSString *)usuari: (NSString *)clau;

@end
```

in .m file is synthesized and released. appData is properly filled when connection request ends and then, when I reload tableview, when numberOfRowsInSection executed (while loop also in order to test), appData is empty!

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);

    self.appData = [[request responseString] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"]; 

    int x =0;

    while (x<[appData count] - 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Aplicaciones = %@",[appData objectAtIndex: x]);
        x = x+1;
    }

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    status.hidden = YES;
    mainTable.hidden = NO;

    [mainTable reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{     
    if ([appData count] != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Counter = %@",[appData objectAtIndex:0]);
    }

    return [appData count]-1;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" ?

Comment: `while (x<[appData count] - 1)` if your array contains 1 element it won't enter the loop and `numberOfRowsInSection` will return 0. And I don't understand why you put a while loop to debug your code in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: yes, agree, my mistake copying code. Already edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here.

Your test logging in `numberOfRows` will cause the app to hang if appdata ever has a non-zero count.

Are you sure you are getting the the same `appData` object that you populate in `requestFinished` ?

I suggest using the accessor in numberOfRows as in `[self.appData count]` which might sort out the problem.

And is there a specific reason you subtract one from the count? As you will lose one element from the array in the tableView that way

Comment: [self.appData count] is most likely will fix it.

Comment: Answers: Yes,same object populated in request finished. 1 is substracted because is and end string and no useful data to show

Comment: Are you returning at least 1 for numberOfSections delegate method?

Comment: Solved, asirequest was triggered before view controller finish launching, so appData was not properly allocated! Thanks to make me look inside!